# How do I get out of Meta and back to the regular forums on medical sciences?

Tags: discussion

It put me here in Meta for no good reason. How do I navigate out of that and back into the regular eg medicinal chemistry or closest to it? I assume it's a bug in the system that put me here in meta? with no obvious way to get out.

Comment: No slight idea what you're talking about

Comment: This site is a beta site. There is no non-beta site to get into. There is a meta site, which is where your question belongs, for discussing the site itself. but the answer to your question is that you have already found what you're looking for.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron isn't it just that they're confused about being in Meat rather than Main? See my answer. The title accidentally says "Beta" but the body says "Meta".

Comment: @user1271772 ironically, you made similar mistake, with "Meat". Unless it's on purpose? lol. Anyway, I won't waste time answering based on guessing the question, but well done for trying. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron Yea it's hilarious that I typed "Meat" .... Basically a typo when trying to say that something is a typo! At least V2Blast seems to agree with me though that the user meant "Meta" and not "Beta".

Comment: @user1271772 lol yeah, worse things happen with autocorrect, believe me. :D

Comment: @user1271772 and Shadow: it's because there is a law waiting for you: [Muphry's law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muphry's_law)

Answer (score 3):

The title of your question says "Beta" but the body of your question says "Meta". To get from Meta back to Main, you can click the [burger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) at the top of the page, and then click on "Medical Sciences" which is next to a blue icon, as opposed to "Medical Sciences Meta" which is next to a black icon.